# Passive low-pass filtering question for a transducer output

Tags: noise, passive-networks, active-filter, passive-filter

I'm having ringing-noise from a pressure transducer analog output.
Here is the only information about the instrument:
http://www.trescal.be/pdf/PPC500_GB_SI.pdf

Let me briefly explain the device and the issue:

This device has an internal analog to digital conversion at some stage and outputs that information on its display. The output from digital data displayed on the screen can be sent via RS-232 directly or as an analog output which is created using digital to analog  conversion. The both RS-232 and analogue output sends the averaged voltages from the transducer at a rate of around three times per second.

For some reason I have to use the analog output. I record the readings from the analog output by a data-acquisition device which has 1GigaOhm input impedance. The DAQ device has many analog inputs and one of the analog inputs comes from this pressure transducer via a BNC cable which is between 10 up-to 15 meters long. All the analog inputs share the same ground and only at this transducer's channel I'm observing  ringing-like noise. Same noise is observed if I hook the BNC up to an oscilloscope.

Below is an example of the transducer's analog signal in question. It shows the signal in time series for 60 seconds which is sampled at  8000 Hertz and plotted in LTspice:
[image]

Here below if I zoom the signal, please see the three steps of discrete voltage sent by the transducer’s analog output per second:
[image]

It seems like there is no reconstruction filter on the output of the transducer’s DAC. But actually it doesn’t matter in my case. What bothers is mostly those crazy jumps/ringings on the edges which sometimes exceeds one volt.
And here below I'm directly zooming to the crazy ringing-edge and by using LTspice's cursors I find out that the ringing-noise is around 1kHz:
[image]

So I decided to use a RC passive low-pass filter but only checked in LTspice and the simulation results are below (V1 is the output from the traducer; C1 and R2 represents the low-pass filter; R1 is the input impedance of the data acquisition channel; green plot shows after filtering):
[image]

And for a better comparison before(blue) and after the filter(green) here:
[image]

> Here are my concerns and questions:

**1-)** I found the solution by filtering. It seems to me the loading is
negligible due to the huge input impedance of the DAQ channel here. So do you agree in this case to use these R2 C1 values are optimum for a passive low-pass filter to eliminate 1kHz?

**2-)** Do you think this passive filter enough here? Is active filter necessary(I haven’t built any yet)?

**3-)** What could be the reason for this ringing? Could it be length of
BNC or inductive effect? (It seems like we have an DAC outputting 3Hz discrete signal sent via a BNC coax cable)

Comment: Any square wave will have ringing if you zoom in enough. It is due to usually the inductance of the wires. I would say the filter is enough assuming the signal can still have a response time that meets your criteria.

Comment: so no need to go for an active filter i guess here. it is 1kHz. how about the choice of RC values? could there be a better combination?

Comment: Seems reasonable to me... Active filters help if your ADC for example had a low impedance, also it is easier to build high order filters using only RC in active configurations.

Comment: Along MadHatter suggestion, just want to say that a quad opamp can house an 8th order Bessel, or Gaussian.

Comment: i see, it would be nice to see the difference. they are also sharper in cut off region. i guess i would find many info about opamp active low-pass filter. have you ever built one? would you recommend any topology or an opamp?

Comment: @MadHatter "high order filters using only RC". maybe i should look for this one as well. would be great to have an answer with an example of higher order one for this case.

Comment: You may be loading the output stage of the transducer with too much stray capacitance (due to cable length) causing slight instability. Try adding series resistance (100 ohm to 1k) as close to the transducer as possible. Keep the capacitor at the ADC input for general noise immunuty.

Comment: @Matthew do you mean the 100 - 1kOhm will be in series just at the output of the transducer? and when you say "keep the capacitor", do you mean keeping the "both R1 C2 in my question" just before the ADC input or only the cap?

Comment: I don 't think this is about any ringing or filtering. To begin, OP says "I record the readings from the analog output by a data-acquisition device which has 1GigaOhm input impedance." Really? 1GOhms?

Comment: @AliChen it is actually 100Gohm. same ringing observed with the scope

Comment: Yes, the resistor would just be at the output of the transducer. I am effectively saying keep R2 and C1, but have them at opposite ends of the cable.

Comment: Wow. 100G! Maybe you should start by looking at your analog output by a simple oscilloscope with a standard 1M passive probe? Then maybe you need to start with identifying the source of the problem, and not filtering of spikes that should not be there in first place. The presented input signal does not make any sense for any normal instrument, unless you use the calibrator as a sensor to some odd turbulent flow, but are not telling this to us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1). Confirm output impedance of Analog sensor output by load test for ~50% drop

- complementary emitter followers used in Op Amps or discrete are notorious for resonance with capacitive loads from 100pF/m cables and current limiting causes low out followed by overshoot followed by ringing at loop gain BW of Op Amp

  - This may be what is happening
- this is where current mode converters work better 4-20mA with separate return wire, shielded or twisted pair and CM ferrite sleeve.
- add 100-300 R series at source to verify reduction in edge pulse
- then load destination with 1k to reduce stray noise coupling and verify voltage drop if any. You may need a power op amp buffer with 120 Ohm source and low impedance load to reject stray coupling or whatever cable Z you are using.
- check with proper high speed measurements for RF noise and LPF as required to rule out RF aliasing noise at 8kHz sampling rate

  - consider **10mH** CM choke and RF cap across output for 50/60Hz and up noise
  - example of your CM 50Hz noise showing up as a differential mode (DM) signal
  - due to unbalanced source and load Z on 50 Ohm coax.
    [image]
  - Is a shame to degrade an instrument with > 60dB SNR down to 20 dB with improper analog cable maybe 30~40dB SNR with filter

Comment: 1k parallel load to reduce stray noise coupling would be less effective than having the OPs 7.2k and 47nF input filter at the ADC and a 100 ohm - 1k series resistor at the transducer output.

Comment: perhaps same, I wrote that part before comments, but essentially matching source impedance and current limit with source R to cable C then "signal spectrum" matched filter at destination. Then verify with R divider of same equiv at source to verify noise only to Vdc, If noise is same then other noise sources exist. e.g. 50/60 Hz which is evident in filtered signal

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 would it be too much demanding if you would draw an illustration/diagram/connections on what you mean or suggest? i'm kind of lost when i read you and cannot imagine the picture. the setup is: there is transducer there is the daq input and there is a BNC in between. otherwise thanks anyway.

Comment: I dont have tools to show CM choke and twisted pair.  Coax is not good for an unbalanced source and unbalanced high impedance load.  Shielded twisted pair is better with balanced diff input.  Multiple grounds from multiple locations also explains line noise. A Balun or CM choke can be a coupled coil pair. Unbalanced signals means CM coupling causes DM noise

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 yes i knew about the 50Hz noise is there but since the average voltage matters in measurements, it cancels right? average of sinusoidal is zero. i would be very glad what you meant by "Is a shame to degrade an instrument with > 60dB SNR down to 20 dB with improper analog cable maybe 30~40dB SNR with filter" how did you come up with that(where does 30 40 come from what are they?)? and as last you wrote "I dont have tools to show CM choke". i meant maybe you can draw on LTspice or MS-paint the diagram you suggest not the actual choke.

Comment: ..something like this way of explaining(example) :https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSrq1wgeFvUKwIb7F6lJm6djRPcYnnio_GUeAisQD44AXNerGRVeQ.

Comment: 40 dB SNR means 1% voltage noise , 20dB SNR means 10% voltage noise,  0.1%  accuracy  implies -60dB error

Comment: yes averaging can reduce ripple somewhat,  no CM choke is not crossed, or raises impedance of each line (CM) to Balance , twisted pair with INA or diff amp,works well too at low f. I would use twisted pair, no, shared  gnd, with Diff amp  before ADC.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I want to do a load test to calculate the output impedance of this transducer following this guide: http://www.qsl.net/w/w2aew//youtube/How_to_measure_output_impedance.pdf But Im just a bit worried to load the transducer too much. I dont know the max current it can source, so I don't want to damage it. In other words what Rload should I choose here?  What could be done in this case? thanks

Comment: try 300 ohms to 3k pullup to 5V and watch for a 10% rise then you know for DC output impedance must be 9x bigger for 10:1  Normally an op Amp is current limited from 0.1mA to 30mA and short circuit protected by internal current limiters, you could also call OEM tech support too and ask them

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the output of the instrument (used as a sensor) has some really noisy pressure input and the internal instrument workings do produce this kind of jumpy output, the answers are:

1. Yes, a simple RC filter with 1kHz cut-off is an acceptable solution
2. Yes, the data show that this is good enough;
3. Most likely reason for the ringing at 1kHz is a flaw in instrument's design of output stage of internal DAC. The 1 kHz ringing cannot be explained by cable/load mismatches.

SIDE NOTE: It looks quite obvious that the selection of this sensor is inadequate to the nature of input pressure signal. The instrument states "settling time" of ~0.5s, which limits the spectrum of input signals to pretty much static pressure levels.

Comment: http://www.analog.com/library/analogdialogue/archives/38-06/capacitive_loading.html?doc=CN0343.pdf shows that capacitive loading of opamps can cause ringing and oscillation. It is a fact. A web search will show more evidence if you need it. 10-15 m of cable can have around 1nF of capacitance. This is more than enough capacitance to cause problems. Adding an "isolation" resistor in series with the output is one of the simple solutions, and particularly suitable for this application

Comment: Still it points to the product design defect, if the DAC buffer failed to handle a reasonable load. However, I did miss the 15m BNC (RG-58U?) of analog cable, which cannot be named as reasonable connection either. Still I see the entire issue as misapplication of pressure sensor.

Comment: 0.5s may be large step response time but small signal and noise spectrum appears to be up to 50 Hz, so the -6dB spectrum may be somewhere in between. Generally optimal filtering matches the desired signal spectrum. It is apparent the OP did not do his homework on the instrument signals before design for transmitted measurements and EMI control. The digital interface would have been smarter.

Answer (score 0):

Transducers are very sensitive instruments. Your signal is probably not the actual transducer signal that the device is processing. I know that magnetic transducers on fathometers and fish finders use amps, not filters to straighten out the signal pre-processing. The fact is I don't know a lot about the processors used with transducers, but I do know that if you filter a tranducer signal, you lose the signal rather than reduce the noise in the line.

I remember once when I was playing with a transducer booster, and the thing started squealing and stopped only after I pulled the plug! I also know that the reason transducers work is because they are powered, and not passive. Filters are generally used in passive circuits, so you will want to use an active filter too.

Good luck, don't fry the transducer... they are very sensitive to their input signal, and can't take any extra resistance at the output, or they will blow their filaments.

Comment: Special note... most transducers are not serial... they are parallel or worse!